# How to pause/resume handler/runnable?

Tags: java, android, timer, handler, runnable

I want to press a button and have that button trigger a timer that increases a variable every second. When I close the app I want that increasing to pause and when the app opens I want it to resume from where it last was. What do I need to do?

Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    public void save(){
        Editor editor = pref.edit();
        editor.putInt("countertest", counter);
        editor.commit();
    }//end of save


    public void read(){
        counter = pref.getInt("countertest", counter);
    }//end of read


      Handler testHandler = new Handler();
      int counter;
      TextView testView;
      Button testButton;
      Runnable Runnable0;
      SharedPreferences pref;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        testView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.testView);
        testButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.testButton);
        pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);



      read();
        testView.setText(Integer.toString(counter));




    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


@Override
protected void onResume() {


    read();


   final Runnable Runnable0 = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            counter += 1;   
            testView.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
            testHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
            save();
            }// end of if   
    };




    /* button click */
    testButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            /* Start runnable */

                testButton.setEnabled(false);
                counter -= 5;
                save();
                testView.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
                testHandler.post(Runnable0);



        }// end of onClick
    });// end of blingButton onClickListener    

    super.onResume();

}//end of onResume

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    save();
    testHandler.removeCallbacks(Runnable0);
    super.onPause();
}//end of onPause
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should store the last time your `Runnable` got called (in millseconds probably) in a variable something like this:

```
int lastRunnableCall = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
```

Then store the current time in a variable when `onPause` gets called. Something like this:

```
int onPauseTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
```

In your `onResume` if you have a value stored for on pause time you can work out the correct post delayed time.

```
int postDelayedTime = onPauseTime > 0 ? 1000 - (onPauseTime - lastRunnableCall) : 1000;
```

Without trying this I don't know how accurate it will be. But this is where I would start

Comment: Where would I want to store the "int lastRunnableCall = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();"? In onCreate?

Comment: I don't understand your explanation and I still can't get it to work.

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. `lastRunnableCall` and `onPauseTime` would be variables on your activity. You would set `lastRunnableCall` every time your `run()` method is called and you would set `onPauseTime` when `onPause()` is called

Comment: This approach would only work if your activity didn't get destoryed in which case it would start fresh. You should look into the android lifecycle to understand this a little more. http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html

Comment: Is it suppose to be `int lastRunnableCall = (int) Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();` with the int typecast, otherwise I get an error.   Also, When I do as you said, the variables `onPauseTime` and `lastRunnableCall` are not recognized as variables in my `onResume()`, even though I called them in the respective places you mentioned.

Comment: Sorry, it didn't make it that clear. the `int` should be a `long` (I should have checked that really) and you should declare them at the top of your `Activity` and set them in methods I said

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood my question lol. I'm not trying to save the time. I'm trying to make a runnable/handler pause when the app is closed and then resume when the app is resumed.

Comment: Do you mind that it starts again with the remaining time the same? for example if it stopped half way through its timer do you need it to start again from the same point? or just start again from 0?

Comment: I suppose. I'm not using it as a timer but it seems to be essentially the same thing. I'm not worried about the 1000 milliseconds though. I'm trying to make a game and once a button is pressed a `textView` will display a value or "points." So the timer could trigger the `textView` to display points that increment every 1000 milliseconds. Does that seem more clear, it is complicated to explain, I apologize.